# Would it work if I plugged my telephone line directly into the Ethernet switch?

Tags: networking

Can I plug the telephone line into an Ethernet switch? Would it work so I get network/internet access if the router is also connected to the same switch or should the telephone line be plugged directly into the router?

Answer (score 0):

NO - they're different mediums.  A telephone line uses RJ11 connectors and Ethernet uses RJ45 connectors. I know it seems to fit but just plug it into the router.

Comment: I told them so but the guys who made the network plugged the line into the switch and told me it was working before and they changed the router and it doesn't work anymore I didn't believed that worked the first time

Comment: it may work but it's not going to work 100%. It's a different type of cable.  It's not going to be able to carry the data in the same way say a cat5e cable is going to.

Comment: Correct answer, but wrong reason. The reason is not because of *"different medium"*, different connectors or *"different type of cable"* (all those could be changed to match).  It doesn't work because of what you cannot see, the electrical signals, are completely different.  The modulation (voltages, timing, phasing) and data protocols are different between Ethernet and phone (analog voice, digital voice and ADSL).  The phone line needs a **modem**, not a router, to interface to an Ethernet network.

Comment: you're right.  I was reading that he was using a switch to bridge a connection to the modem.  Like he didn't have enough cable and was going to use a switch to connect the two, from the wall to the router's correct port just using a switch in between.